# How to make node module depend on another module that is installed in a target project

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am writing a node module (isSameAs) that adds some functionality to a module (class-validator) that is already installed in my project.

When I had it inside of my project it worked, but after I extracted it to a separate module it stopped working. This module depends on a `class-validator` module so I installed it inside of a module directory.

I assume that because of 2 instances of the module I am trying to modify (`project/node_modules/class-validator` and `project/node_modules/my_module/class-validator`)
it overwrites `class-validator` which is inside of my module directory which is wrong.

**Code of my module**

index.js

```js
import { registerDecorator } from "class-validator";

export function IsSameAs() {
    console.log('value is the same');
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "class-validator": "^0.11.0"
}
```

**Project that uses my module and `class-validator`**

validation.js

```
import { IsSameAs } from 'class-validator-same-as';
```

package.json

```
"class-validator": "^0.11.0",
"class-validator-same-as": "file:../class-validator-isSameAs",
```

So obviously, there is a second instance of class-validator inside of my module, is there a way not to install `class-validator` inside of my module but instead use the global one?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

- Re-export the `class-validator` module/functions from your `class-validator-same-as` module. In your main project, you will only import your `class-validator-same-as` module.
- Use dependency injection to inject `class-validator` module/functions into your `class-validator-same-as` module. You import `class-validator` only into your main project and provide a reference to `class-validator` to your `class-validator-same-as` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use peer dependence, this way you can tell explicitly that your package needs other package to be installed. The user will even get a neat message when installing your package without that depedencies.

The package.json for your module will be something like

```js
"peerDependencies": {
  "class-validator": "^0.11.0"
}
```

You can read more on peer dependece [here](https://nodejs.org/ru/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: This way I am getting an error "Cannot find module 'class-validator' because my package depends on a module and uses it functionality

Comment: During tests in your package or in the greater environment with both packages installed?